# Set Dropdownlist value in listview on itemdatabound

Tags: asp.net, listview, itemdatabound

i have dropdownlist of year which is coming dynamically.i have filled the dropdownlist using object datasource.on inserting in the listview control it is working fine. but when i click on edit button that dropdownlist value should  be set which is coming from the database.
  e.g. if i have a row which contains Year=2006 and month="Jan"
then on click on edit button these dropdown list should be fill up.

i have written the code in ItemDataBound to set the value of the dropdownlilst.but when i use findcontrol its taking null so object reference error is coming. so please provide me the solution.

thanks

samir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have written the below code

protected void ListView_Articles_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e )
        {

```
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
        {
            if (cmd == "edit")
            {
                // Display the e-mail address in italics.
                int month, year;
                month = Convert.ToDateTime(DataBinder.Eval(((ListViewDataItem)e.Item).DataItem,"Created")).Month;
                year = Convert.ToDateTime(DataBinder.Eval(((ListViewDataItem)e.Item).DataItem, "Created")).Year;
                ListViewDataItem item = (ListViewDataItem)e.Item;

                DropDownList ddlmonth = (DropDownList)e.Item.FindControl("ddlmonth");
                DropDownList ddlyear = (DropDownList)e.Item.FindControl("ddlyear");
                ListItem lstitem = ddlyear.Items.FindByValue(year.ToString());
```

// i found that ddlyear is null so it unable to bind the data.

```
if (ddlmonth != null)
                {
                    foreach (ListItem monthitem in ddlmonth.Items)
                    {
                        if (int.Parse(monthitem.Value) == month)
                        {
                            ddlmonth.ClearSelection();
                            monthitem.Selected = true;
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (ddlyear != null)
                {
                    foreach (ListItem yearitem in ddlyear.Items)
                   {
                       if (int.Parse(yearitem.Value) == year)
                        {
                           ddlyear.ClearSelection();
                            yearitem.Selected = true;
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }


    }
```

Comment: i have solved the problem .remove the foreach loop and instead of it write ddlyear.selectedvalue=year, and same for month also.

Answer (score 2):

```
 protected void MyListView_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
 {
     if (e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
     {
          DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)e.Item.FindControl("nameOfDDLOnAspxPage");
          ddl.SelectValue = (however you are getting the year data for this row);
     }
 }
```